# what are the contents of a .lst file generated by masm program?

Tags: assembly, masm

while running the assembly language programs using masm .lst, files are generated.
What are the exact contents of this .lst files and why is this conversion essential?

Comment: Back in the olden days, assembly programmers didn't have very good debuggers or an operating system that permitted debugging and code viewing at the same time.  So a listing file that was formatted for a printer was a good way to have something to look at while troubleshooting code.  Paper consumption was stupendous btw.

Comment: @Hans Passant That sounds like an answer.

Comment: It's more like an anecdote from the time of the dinosaurs :)

Comment: @HansPassant There are still some dinosaurs running around here on SO, and sometimes they like to be reminded of the good old times :-)

Comment: @HansPassant thanks a lot sir... that was of great help

Comment: maybe you accept his answer to keep this site rollin'? And I remember jumping around (felt like) 2miles of tractor paper.

Comment: hahahaa i just realized that he did not "answer". sry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being another dinosaur, I think we should promote Hans Passant's comment into an answer.

> Back in the olden days, assembly programmers didn't have very good debuggers or an operating system that permitted debugging and code viewing at the same time. So a listing file that was formatted for a printer was a good way to have something to look at while troubleshooting code. Paper consumption was stupendous btw. – Hans Passant May 8 at 17:28

Programming using paper and pencil is a lost art. Not missed by many.